How to use a variable to find data in a dictionary
I have a dictionary and I want to access different parts of the dictionary based on the output of a random generator. Since I do not know what the output would be of the random generator I want to use the name of the variable generated to access the dictionary.
So here is my dictionary:
let powerups = {
    "pizza":["You gained super strength!"],
    "cupcake":["You gained super speed!"],
    "goblin soup":["You turned into a goblin!"],
    "the finger":["Nothing happened!"],
    "pasta":["You are now super flexible!"]
};

And I am trying to access the dictionary in this function.
let foodOptions = ["pizza", "cupcake", "goblin soup", "finger", "pasta"]

function foodWheelManager(list) {
    println("Spinning wheel.")
    let food = foodOptions[Math.floor(Math.random()*foodOptions.length)];
    println("You eat the " + food + ".");
    println(powerups.food[0]);
    println("Game over you won!");
}

So here you can see that this code:
println(powerups.food[0]);

is not working. This code is what is giving the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') I am super new to coding, so any help would be amazing. Thank you!

powerups[food][0]

powerups[food].at(0)

your code won't work when you get the finger option because your powerup object  has the finger as key but in your foodOptions array you only have finger

You need to create a function which will return you random key. Something like this:
function getRandomKey(){
 let seed = Math.floor(Math.random() * foodOptions.length);
 return foodOptions[seed];
}

..
let key=getRandomKey();
println(powerups[key]);
..

